# Why can't I submit this form?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

Can someone explain me why the `submit` event is never fired when pressing `enter` key in the input?

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="press enter here"/>
  <button disabled>disabled</button>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Clicking on the submit button works well.
If I remove the disabled button it works well.

Tested under:
- Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Build officiel) (64 bits)
- Chrome Version 68.0.3439.0 (Build officiel) canary (64 bits)

The first button is disabled but not the second which have `type="submit"`.

Is that a known issue? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. The relevant part of the HTML5 standard is [§4.10.21.2 "Implicit submission"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission):

> A `form` element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text control is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form, whose default button has activation behavior and is not disabled, must cause the user agent to fire a `click` event at that default button.

The first submit button in the form is always treated as the default button, even if it is disabled. Disabling it prevents it from being used to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the HTML spec, this is what is was looking for! cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the first button to type="button"

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="press enter here" />
    <button type="button" disabled>disabled</button>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

If you're not going to use the first button to submit the form, then it doesn't need to be declared as a submit button. If you don't declare it, the form likely thinks it should be the button that submits the form. (Because it's the first button the browser sees when the <del>page</del> **form** is parsed)

Comment: `Because it's the first button the browser sees when the page is parsed`: still looking weird to me. Browser cannot see that the button right after was in fact the "real" submit button and redeclare it?

Comment: When clicking "enter" the form is using the closest submit button to execute the form. If you want to change which one is used, you can click the tab button. But, without doing this an "enter" submit event will click the closest submit button. Because this button was seen as disabled the browser isn't skipping to the next one, it's just killing the submission.